# Changing flex from parent and child at the same time triggers a flickering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have this structure:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="document-reader-root">
    <div class="left-bar">
       Left bar
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right-bar">
    Right bar
  </div>
</div>
```

And after a click on a button, I'm changing the flex size of the `left-bar` and `content` but this triggers a small movement of the content. It's hard to explain it in words so I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matiastucci/ckoa805q/10/) to demonstrate it. FYI, I *can't* change the structure of the divs.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the content size when the sidebars get hidden away

```
.doc-content {
   transition: max-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.hide-panels {
  .doc-content {
    max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

Changing the `max-width` makes the flickering go away

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have is that you are animating CSS properties that don't fall under the 60 frames-per-second (FPS) specification. When you animate such properties you get jitter / flickering.

Properties that have buttery smooth 60FPS are `transform` and `opacity`. Properties such as `flex`, `margin`, `top` etc are known to be prone to flicker when animated.

You can read more about it here: [Animation performance and frame rate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Animation_performance_and_frame_rate). The section related to your problem is under 'CSS property cost'

**Note:** although Firefox also uses this specficiation, even at 60fps, animations are sometimes prone to flicker due to sub-pixel rendering issues (this isn't what is causing your problem though - [Firefox sub-pixel rendering bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176), but it is handy to know).